# A space isometric to $\ell_\infty^2$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-theory, norms, isometries

Consider a norm on $\mathbb C^2$ as $\|(z_1,z_2)\|:=\max\{|z_1|,|z_2|,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|z_1+iz_2|\}.$

*Question.* Is $(\mathbb C^2,\|.\|)$ linearly isometric to $(\mathbb C^2,\|.\|_{\infty})$ where $\|(z_1,z_2)\|_\infty:=\max\{|z_1|,|z_2|\}?$

Comment: By the Mazur-Ulam theorem, if there exists a bijective isometry between those two spaces, then such an isometry is real affine, so by translating that isometry must be real linear. Have you calculated the set of extreme points of the unit balls of these spaces? Do they have the same spaces of extreme points on unit balls?

Comment: @Joseph. By isometry I mean linear isometry only. Ibhave edited my question.

Comment: The two norms are literally identical because $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|z_1 + iz_2| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{|z_1|^2 + |z_2|^2}$ can never exceed ${\rm max}(|z_1|, |z_2|)$.

Comment: @NikWeaver ... that is wrong, note $z_1$ and $z_2$ are complex, so in general $|z_1+iz_2|^2 \ne |z_1|^2+|z_2|^2$.

Comment: Oh I was misinterpreting the formula, thinking $z_1$ and $z_2$ were orthogonal. You're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such map $f$. Let's try to map from the second space (with the funny norm, which I'll denote simply by $\|\cdot\|$) back to $(\mathbb C^2, \|\cdot \|_{\infty})$. Let $u=f(e_1)$, $v=f(e_2)$, so $\|u\|_{\infty}=\|v\|_{\infty}=1$. Since $|1\pm i|^2=2$, so $\|(1,\pm 1)\|=1$, we also have $\|u\pm v\|_{\infty}=1$. However, if $|z|=1$ and $w\not= 0$, then $|z\pm w|>1$ for one choice of sign. So if (say) $|u_1|=1$, then $v_1=0$. It follows that $u=e^{i\alpha}e_1$, $v=e^{i\beta}e_2$, or the other way around.

But then $\|f((1,-i)/\sqrt{2})\|_{\infty}=1/\sqrt{2}$ even though $\|(1,-i)/\sqrt{2}\|=1$.

Answer (score 2):

**comment**
I think they are not isometric, having different structure for the set of extreme points.

The set of extreme points for the unit ball of $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ is a torus: $$T = \{(z_1,z_2) : |z_1| = |z_2| = 1\}.$$

The set of extreme points of the unit ball of $\|\cdot\|$ perhaps consist of the union of three tori: $$T_1 = \{(z_1,z_2) : |z_1|=|z_2| = 1\},\\T_2 = \textstyle\{(z_1,z_2) : |z_1|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|z_1+iz_2| = 1\},\\T_3 = \{(z_1,z_2) : |z_2|=\textstyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|z_1+iz_2| = 1\}.$$

Here is an example of a point in $T_2$ but not $T_1$:
$$
\left(1,\;
\frac{\sqrt{-r^4+6r^2-1}}{2} + i\,\frac{r^2-1}{2}\right),\quad
\sqrt{2}-1 < r < 1 .
$$

---

Now all that remains is to prove this...

Comment: One has to intersect the three tori with the unit ball w.r.t $\|\cdot\|$ since $T_i$ is not a subset of the unit ball for $1\leq i\leq 3$. One should define $T_1=\{(z_1,z_2):|z_1|=|z_2|=1,|z_1+iz_2|\leq\sqrt{2}\}$.

Comment: @Gerald. Maybe one can show that the unit ball has a boundary which is not smooth and so it is not isometric.

Comment: I think both of these are non-smooth.